# How to cut HTML file (drop anything outside two tags)?

Tags: html, awk, sed, jq, sequential

When this is my HTML example document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <div class="text">TEST</div>
    <div id="trend" data-app="openableBox" class="box sub-box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h1><span>Highlights</span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I extract

```
<iframe></iframe>
<div class="text">TEST</div>
```

by dropping everything *before* `<iframe>` and *after* (beginning with)`<div id="trend">`?

Thanks if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that solves the general problem, assuming one wants to select a range of elements based on a "linearization" of the HTML.  This solution uses [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to convert HTML to JSON, and then uses [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to perform the linearization, selection, and conversion back to HTML.

### program.jq

The idea is to "linearize" the HTML by recursively hoisting the children to the top-level:

```
# Emit a stream by hoisting .children recursively.
# It is assumed that the input is an array, 
# and that .children is always an array.
def hoist:
  .[]
  | if type == "object" and has("children")
    then del(.children), (.children | hoist)
    else .
    end;

def indexof(condition):
  label $out
  | foreach .[] as $x (null; .+1;
      if ($x|condition) then .-1, break $out else empty end)
    // null;

# Reconstitute the HTML element
def toHtml:
  def k: . as $in | (keys_unsorted - ["tag", "text"])
  | reduce .[] as $k (""; . + " \($k)=\"\($in[$k])\"");
  def t: if .text then .text else "" end;
  "<\(.tag)\(k)>\(t)</\(.tag)>"
  ;

# Linearize and then select the desired range of elements
[hoist]
| indexof( .tag == "iframe") as $first
| indexof( .tag == "div" and .id=="trend") as $last
| .[$first:$last]
| .[]
| toHtml
```

### Invocation:

```
pup 'json{}' < input.html | jq -rf program.jq
```

### Output:

```
<iframe></iframe>
<div class="text">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with HTML/XML data from the command line - a proper HTML/XML parser should be used. 
**`xmllint`** is one of such.

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//body/*[self::iframe or self::div[@class="text"]]' input.html
```

The output:

```
<iframe></iframe><div class="text">TEST</div>
```

Comment: [tag:xmlstarlet] is another such tool: `xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//body/*[self::iframe or self::div[@id="trend"]]' input.html`

Comment: @glennjackman, `xmlstarlet` would fail in this case with error: `1.html:6.10: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 4 and head
  </head>
         ^
1.html:16.9: Opening and ending tag mismatch: head line 3 and html
</html>
       ^
1.html:17.1: Premature end of data in tag html line 2
`. That's why I picked `xmllint` (because of html input)

Comment: Right, need to fix the `meta` tag to be proper XML. I didn't realize xmllint could handle non-xml html.

Comment: Would it still work when the HTML tags are scattered overed multiple lines?

Comment: @LuisPaganini, in such approach it does not matter whether a tag occupies one or multiple lines